# REST API Teamcity - Get list of changes that contain a specific tag

Tags: api, rest, teamcity

Ultimately, I want to have a list of all build configurations that contain any changes with a specific version tag.  Based on what I am seeing in the documentation, this should work to get me the raw data that I can form to my needs:

`http://<server>/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/?locator=tags:($version),count:50000`

I've tried using specific version number tags and the stable tag, and even with 50000 results, it finds zero when looking for tags.  I removed the tag locator, and got 49,000+ results, so I know that part works.

Even with a list of builds or changes, the response doesn't have any tag information on those results to even parse through.

Am I missing something?  Is there a better way to get this information out of TeamCity through the API?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your **$version** variable references, but here's an example that can get the information back for a known tag name.

1. Tag a build - here I'm using the tag **mytag**

[image]

2. Use the following request to get the builds back that have the known tag, and also return the changes.

   `http://<server>/httpAuth/app/rest/builds?locator=tags(mytag)&fields=build(changes(change),tags(tag))`

[image]

If you want to return additional information about the build you'll have to add it to the fields information e.g.

`http://<server>/httpAuth/app/rest/builds?locator=tags(mytag)&fields=build(id, number, status, changes(change),tags(tag))`

This will return additional information about the build's id, number and status.

[image]

Hope this helps